# Webpack: Debugging build scripts (not the app)

Tags: webpack

I would like to debug the webpack scripts , not the produced app !

How can I configure the build scripts to be launched / used by a node debugger such as devtool ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The webpack binary you run is just JavaScript, so you can debug it like any other script you run. When you install webpack, a symlink `./node_modules/.bin/webpack` is added that refers to [webpack.js](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/bin/webpack.js). You can run the [node debugger](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html) with:

```
node debug ./node_modules/.bin/webpack [options]
```

Or if you want to use Chrome devtools you add the `--inspect` flag:

```
node debug --inspect ./node_modules/.bin/webpack [options]
```

Comment: I would add just that your config might be ````node debug ./node_modules/.bin/webpack [options]```` as in my case (Windows, webpack 3) ````./node_modules/.bin/webpack```` leads to an error.